# Design drawables to maintain proportions in all devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I'm trying to design UI for my android app which maintains a proportional aspect in all devices.

I've already read all [Android developers article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) about this but I don't understand some things yet.

I use the new size qualifiers `(sw320dp,sw480dp,sw600dp,sw720dp)`.

I've started to design the drawables to this configuration:

**layout-sw720dp-land  ---->1280x800 (10" tablet) mdpi**

[image]

The world icon has `50x50px` size and following the developers guide I've scaled the icon to adapt to all densities (for example in `HDPI` the icon size is `100x100px (x1.5 from mdpi)`)

The problem is when I try to show the same activity in this device it looks like this:

**layout-sw320dp-land-----> 1820x768 (4.7")hdpi**

[image]

Both devices has a similar screen resolution but the phone has a **bigger screen density** and **a smaller physical screen size.**

Both images has with and height layout attributes set to `wrap_content`.

What should be the baseline guide to start? The android developers guide says normal screen and mdpi density but I don't know if this is suitable to nowadays

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you put your world image to different `drawable` folder? Also if you set `wrap_content` then it will display the actual size of your image on different mobile screens.

Comment: Yes, I've already put the corresponding drawables into the folders. If I set the layout width/height to `wrap_content` then android doesn't scale it?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is not your fault. 
`layout-sw320dp-land` will pick up drawable from `hdpi` folder whereas `layout-sw720dp-land` is `mdpi` device so it will pick up drawables from `mdpi` folder which will be smaller than `hdpi`.

Comment: Then, How can i solve it? In the android developers guide doesn't speak about this problem

Comment: You can not do anything in that case. Because dependency of pick up drawable on screen density of device.

Comment: No. You have to accept it as it is. You can't do anything.

Comment: Design drawable size in function of `sw` intead of screen density could patch the problem? Can I add the sw qualifier to drawable folders?

Comment: I don't think it's a right way to manage. Even  i never try it because i think it's not actual solution. So, you can try it if you want.

Comment: Even  i did not find any docs. which prefer drawable size in function of sw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75506/discussion-between-samir-bhatt-and-hanzo).

Comment: I think that providing different drawables to different densities allows to maintain the same size of the drawable beetwen densities, but the real problem is the available size on the screen, in my original post when launch the app into the different devices the size of the icon is the same but there are a smaller available space on the screen